# How to deploy an Angular8 application to google app engine using CI-CD process?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, yaml, devops, google-cloud-build

I am trying to deploy my UI application to `google app engine` using the `CI-CD` process. This is totally new to me. Below are the steps that I followed:

1. Mirroed my bitbucket repository.
2. Created `cloudbuild.yaml` and `app.yaml` files.
3. Created a cloud build trigger.

Here is my cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
# Install npm
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  args: ['npm', 'install']
  dir: './UI'
# Build productive file
- name: 'node:10.10.0'
  args: ['npm', 'run', 'build', '--prod']
  dir: './UI'
# Deploy UI to CP-D
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', './']
  dir: './UI'
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url:  /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: EPortal/\1
  upload: EPortal/(.*\.js)

- url:  /favicon.ico
  static_files: EPortal/favicon.ico
  upload: EPortal/assets/favicon.ico

- url:  /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json)(|\.map))$
  static_files: EPortal/\1
  upload: EPortal/(.*)(|\.map)

- url:  /(.*\.svg)
  static_files: EPortal/\1
  upload: EPortal/(.*\.svg)
  mime_type: image/svg+xml

- url:  /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: EPortal/index.html
  upload: EPortal/index\.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Below are the logs generated. Pasting only few logs due to security reasons:

```
Step #2: Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Step #2: Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Step #2: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file [/workspace/UI/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/librsvg-2.so.2], which has size [47123185] (greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Everything is working fine except my `deployment`. Not deploying due to `size` issue. It would be of a great help if you could help me fix this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need `node_modules` in the Python application? It looks like that is just for building a static site. You would want to ignore `node_modules` in this case either:

- Using `skip_files` entry in your application .yaml file just like the error suggests. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files for information on it.
- Adding `node_modules` to an ignore file. Information on this at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Given your current application configuration it might look like:

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
skip_files:
  - node_modules/

handlers:
- url:  /(.*\.js)
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_files: EPortal/\1
  upload: EPortal/(.*\.js)

- url:  /favicon.ico
  static_files: EPortal/favicon.ico
  upload: EPortal/assets/favicon.ico

- url:  /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|json)(|\.map))$
  static_files: EPortal/\1
  upload: EPortal/(.*)(|\.map)

- url:  /(.*\.svg)
  static_files: EPortal/\1
  upload: EPortal/(.*\.svg)
  mime_type: image/svg+xml

- url:  /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: EPortal/index.html
  upload: EPortal/index\.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Andy! :) This solved my issue.

Comment: Hi Andy, when the `build` step from `cloudbuild.yaml` file is executed, it creates a default `dist` directory wherein there is a build file which has to be deployed. But, when the `deploy` step from `cloudbuild.yaml` is executed, it gets deployed successfully, but when I check my server, my application which was previously up and running goes down.

`Note: This is an Angular8 application.`